# How to bind a style to a property of whatever datacontext has the styled element?

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, datacontext

I have a datatrigger inside a style trigger like the following one

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="ChangeAnimation" >
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=APropertyOfTheDataGridCellContext Bind DataContext}" Value="True" >
            ...
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I will apply this style to some DataGridColumns using the property CellStyle. What I would like is to bind the DataTrigger of the style to a property of the datacontext of the cell, this way I will be able to use this Style on all of the required columns instead of having to create a new Style for each column. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: To clarify, the DataContext of the DataGrid is a ViewModel with a property called Rows and the Rows has a property called Cells with a property called Blink. I want to reference the property inside the style like this:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="ChangeAnimation" >
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Blink}" Value="True" >
            ...
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

This gives me an error aws the DataGridResources datacontext is the one containing the Rows not the cells one. How can I reference the DataGridCell DataContext from the style?

Answer (score 5):

Removing The `x:Key` attribute then that will be appliced to all the columns.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}"> 
    <Style.Triggers>         
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.MyProperty,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}}" Value="True" />                       
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

If you have 2 DataGrids then you should keep this style in the `Resources` tag of the dataGrid you want to modify ...

If RelativeSource is not working i would prefer to change the Template of the Column by a trigger to achive a similar behavior

## Writing Trigger for the Column

```
<WpfToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="50"
                                   MaxWidth="80"
                                   Header="MyHeader"
                                   IsReadOnly="True">
    <WpfToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="normalTemplate" />
                <DataTemplate x:Key="ChangeTempalte">
                   <!-Your Controls->
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataTemplate.Resources>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="chnagedField"
                              Content="{Binding}"
                              ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=normalTemplate}" />
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=MyProperty}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="EditableField" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=chnageTempalte}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </WpfToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</WpfToolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Here `MyProperty` is the Property of the `DataContext` of the `DataGridRow` so you can chose what ever level of nested property yo Compare for that specific row... only downside is that you have to do this for all the column that require this

I hope it helps

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that I'm declaring the Style inside the DataGrid resources. Can I reference a property of the DataGridCell DataContext from there?

Comment: @SoMoS Do yu want to do someting Like this... se edited answer

Comment: Right, something like this but the datacontext is not an ancestor but a child. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @SoMoS Child ?? ... `DataContext` of DataGridCell will Contain a Specific Property from the `DataGridRow`'s `DataContext`.... So I am assuming that DataGridCell `DataContext` has the required property or its a child of the required property so... You can write its as `Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.MyProperty.PropertyChild,Relativeresource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAscestor,AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}" Value="True"`

Also DataContext of DataGridCell will be Object that you have set in Xaml for binding Columns of DataGrid...

Comment: What I mean is that you're binding using a FindAncestor. As the Style is inside DataGrid.Resources the binding will try to resolve the bind looking for an ancestor of the DataGrid, right?

Comment: @SoMoS I got what you are saying... In this case you have to directly write for that specific DataTemplate of the Column.... Thats the only way i can figure out Right now

Comment: Yeah, it helps, the problem is I have like 20 columns and the value will probably increase with time ... ouch ... anyway, thanks!